# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to Datos.Localidad

Tags: java

Mi pregunta es la siguiente, ¿cómo puedo almacenar el identificador y el nombre de la localidad en el momento de auto completar un JComboBox? Porque cuando filtro dentro del combo, quiero almacenar el elemento seleccionado pero me aparece un error.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to Datos.Localidad
```

El código siguiente muestra la línea en la que sale de la excepción entre ///.

```
private void btnGuardarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        if (!txtNombre.getText().isEmpty()) {
            if (!txtApellido.getText().isEmpty()) {
                if (cboLocalidad.getSelectedItem() != null) {
                    cliente.setNombre(txtNombre.getText());
                    cliente.setApellido(txtApellido.getText());
                    cliente.setTelefono(txtTelefono.getText());
                    cliente.setDomicilio(txtDomicilio.getText());
                    cliente.setFacebook(txtFacebook.getText());
                    ////////////////////////////////
                    Localidad cbo = (Localidad) cboLocalidad.getSelectedItem();
                    int id = cbo.getIdlocalidad();
                    ///////////////////////////////
                    cliente.setIdlocalidad(id);
                    cliente.guardar();
                    dispose();
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debe seleccionaar una Localidad.", "Advertencia", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    cboLocalidad.requestFocus();
                }
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debe ingresar un Apellido.", "Advertencia", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                txtApellido.requestFocus();
            }
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debe ingresar un Nombre.", "Advertencia", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            txtNombre.requestFocus();
        }
    }
```

Esa línea de código es necesario para capturar el id seleccionado al seleccionar un ítem en el JComboBox para luego almacenarlo en mi BD. La clase localidad es la siguiente:

```
public class Localidad{
    public int idlocalidad;
    public String localidad;

    public Localidad(int idlocalidad, String localidad) {
        this.idlocalidad = idlocalidad;
        this.localidad = localidad;
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public int getIdlocalidad() {
        return idlocalidad;
    }

    public void setIdlocalidad(int idlocalidad) {
        this.idlocalidad = idlocalidad;
    }

    public String getLocalidad() {
        return localidad;
    }

    public void setLocalidad(String localidad) {
        this.localidad = localidad;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return localidad;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof Localidad)) {
            return false;
        }
        Localidad localidad = (Localidad) obj;
        if (idlocalidad != localidad.idlocalidad) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.localidad != null ? !this.localidad.equals(localidad.localidad) : localidad.localidad != null) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 3;
        hash = 89 * hash + (this.localidad != null ? this.localidad.hashCode() : 0);
        hash = 89 * hash + this.idlocalidad;
        return hash;
    }


}
```

El JComboBox se llena de la siguiente manera.

```
private DefaultComboBoxModel comboLocalidad() {
        DefaultComboBoxModel valor = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
        try {
            Connection miComando = AdministradorConfiguracion.obtenerComandoMySql();
            CallableStatement obtenerLocalidades = miComando.prepareCall("call obtener_localidades()");
            ResultSet rs = obtenerLocalidades.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                cboLocalidad.setModel(valor);
                valor.addElement(new Localidad(rs.getInt("Nro"), rs.getString("Localidad")));
                //Se instancia la clase y se le pasa al constructor los datos cargados en el "rs".
                Localidad cbo = new Localidad(rs.getInt("Nro"), rs.getString("Localidad"));
                //Se establece el elemento que se quiera que esté seleccionado por defecto.
                cbo.idlocalidad = 0;
                cbo.localidad = "";
                cboLocalidad.setSelectedItem(cbo);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al intentar auto completar busqueda:\n"
                    + e, "Error en la operación", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        return valor;
    }
```

Realizo un método el cual sirve para buscar una localidad dentro del jcombobox editable.

```
private void autoCompletarLocalidad(String cadBus) {

        List<String> filterArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        String cadena = "";
        try {
            Connection miComando = AdministradorConfiguracion.obtenerComandoMySql();
            CallableStatement obtenerLocalidades = miComando.prepareCall("call obtener_localidades_por_cadena(?)");
            obtenerLocalidades.setString(1, cadBus);
            ResultSet rs = obtenerLocalidades.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                cadena = rs.getString("Localidad");
                filterArray.add(cadena);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al intentar auto completar busqueda:\n"
                    + e, "Error en la operación", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

        if (filterArray.size() > 0) {
            cboLocalidad.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(filterArray.toArray()));
            cboLocalidad.setSelectedItem(cadBus);
            cboLocalidad.showPopup();
        } else {
            cboLocalidad.hidePopup();
        }
    }
```

Hago un método que invoca el método keyReleased () mientras escribimos se va auto llenando el jcombobox.

```
private void cboAutoComplete() {
        final JTextField textoBuscado = (JTextField) cboLocalidad.getEditor().getEditorComponent();
        textoBuscado.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        autoCompletarLocalidad(textoBuscado.getText());
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Luego los llamo desde el constructor.

```
public AgregarClientes() {
        initComponents();
        comboLocalidad();
        cboAutoComplete();
    }
```

Hasta ahi anda todo ok, el problema surje al buscar una localidad dentro del jcombobox, me dice `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to Datos.Localidad` al pasarle el string y seleccionarlo, cuando hago click en guardar, sale esa excepcion.
Excite alguna otra forma de almacenar el ID del string buscado? 
Espero de a ver sido claro. Desde ya gracias.

Comment: En principio, a tu DefaultComboboxModel le falta el tipo de dato. Por ejemplo:  `DefaultComboBoxModel<String> valor = new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ver...

La base del problema es que en tu método de autocompletar, en el comboBox lo que guardas son sólo `String`; cuando autocompleta haces:

```
List<String> filterArray = new ArrayList<String>();
... // añadir las strings que cumplen el filtro
cboLocalidad.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(filterArray.toArray()));
```

Obviamente, si has guardado `String` te devuelve `String`, y no puedes convertir un `String` a otra clase.

Lo que tienes que hacer es lo que ya haces bien al rellenar originalmente el comboBox... hacer que el modelo trabaje con `Localidad` y rellenar la lista con instancias de dicha clase.

```
valor.addElement(new Localidad(rs.getInt("Nro"), rs.getString("Localidad")));
cboLocalidad.setModel(valor);
```

Notas:

1. Como comenta A. Cedano, estaría bien que te acostumbraras a usar genéricos por todas partes (`DefaultComboBoxModel<Localidad> valor = new DefaultComboBoxModel<Localidad>();`)
2. En `comboLocalidad()`, asignas el modelo a cada iteración de la lectura de resultados. Basta con que lo hagas después de salir del bucle. Igual que lo del `setSelectedItem()`.
3. Con lo del `setSelectedItem()`, si lo que quieres es que no haya ningún elemento seleccionado, basta con que hagas `setSelectedItem(null)`. Y si el modelo está recién creado, ni siquiera eso.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Me re sirvió tu explicación! Recién me estoy iniciando en java y la verdad es un lenguaje hermoso! Cada vez me gusta mas! Mil gracias de verdad.